# Type definitions for get and set for TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, getter-setter

I'm trying to use [axel](https://github.com/F1LT3R/axel/blob/master/index.js) module from my type script code.

Specifically it includes this [functionality](https://github.com/F1LT3R/axel/blob/master/index.js#L49-L56):

```
set brush (character){
  defaultChar = character || ' ';
},

get brush (){
  return defaultChar;
},
```

I'm calling it from my Typescript code like so:

```
ctx.brush = '*'; // per the demos/examples
```

The `index.d.ts` comes from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/axel/index.d.ts) and includes the following definition:

```
declare class Axel {
    brush: string;
    ...
```

So to me everything checks out. Yet when I run it I get an error:

```
src/index.ts:16:13 - error TS2540: Cannot assign to 'brush' because it is a read-only property.

16         ctx.brush = '*';
               ~~~~~
```

What's missing here?

**EDIT**: Full sample code on [github](https://github.com/dmitrym0/gameoflife.ts/blob/master/src/index.ts#L2). I build it with `npm run build`.

The file where axel is being imported and used:

```
import * as Gol from './gameoflife';
import * as ctx from 'axel';
import * as fs from 'fs';
const fd = fs.openSync('/dev/stdin', 'rs')
function main() {

    const map = new Gol.CoordinatesMap();
    map.set(new Gol.Coordinate(5,5), new Gol.Cell());
    map.set(new Gol.Coordinate(5,6), new Gol.Cell());
    map.set(new Gol.Coordinate(5,7), new Gol.Cell());
    map.set(new Gol.Coordinate(4,5), new Gol.Cell());
    map.set(new Gol.Coordinate(4,6), new Gol.Cell());
    let currentWorld = new Gol.World(map);

    for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        ctx.bg(0,0,0);
        ctx.clear();
        ctx.fg(0,255,0);
        // ctx.brush = '*'; // <-- doesn't work
        new Gol.WorldPainter().drawWorld(ctx, currentWorld);
        fs.readSync(fd, new Buffer(1));
        currentWorld = new Gol.NextWorldGenerator(currentWorld).nextWorld();
    }

}



main();
```

Comment: This small example works for me: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwIIA8QXgbwCh5j4AjGAV2QAsAueZAFxgEsA7AcwG4CBfAggDMKbMIxYB7NvEESJACij0sOAJT4iJKADpyVavAC88AEQBmEz15A

Comment: Can you post a minimal yet complete example of how you are importing and using this library? Because this typescript playground can import this library and set the brush without complaint: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAYxgDzgMyhEcDkBDZAUwBscAoMpZAOgCMoBXAZwAs4BeXAKhyA

Comment: @AlexWayne The example project is here: https://github.com/dmitrym0/gameoflife.ts/blob/master/src/index.ts#L2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using:

```
import * as ctx from 'axel'
```

This gathers up all named exports into a single object. But this library doesn't appear to be organized that way. It uses a default export to get the `ctx` object.

That means you don't use `import *`. If you import the default export from the library instead, it should work fine:

```
import ctx from 'axel'
```

---

In general, if the docs say you should do:

```
const myValue = require('mylib')
```

Then in typescript you typically will want to do:

```
import myValue from 'mylib'
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex Wayne, that does indeed work. Where can I read more about this? Would this be under the module system?

Comment: Yeah this page seems to cover the basics: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html